# How to consume an EJB in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, websphere, ejb

I'm trying to inject the `EJB` with a Spring application in a Websphere server to call his methods.

I downloaded the EJB's jar and added it as a Library in the project.
The jar exposes a Remote, which is an interface.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px9sX.png): [EJB Jar in Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px9sX.png)

Then I tried to make Spring understand that it is an EJB.
I put this inside web.xml

```
        <description />
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/AberturaEJBRemoteRef</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <home />
        <remote>
            br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote
        </remote>
        <ejb-link>AberturaEJB</ejb-link>
    </ejb-ref>
```

Then I tried these two configurations at app.context:

First attempt:

```
<jee:remote-slsb id="abertura" jndi- name="ejb/AberturaEJBRemoteRef#br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote"
           business-interface="br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote"
           home-interface="br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote"
           cache-home="false" lookup-home-on-startup="false"
           refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true" />
```

Second attempt:

```
<bean id="abertura"
          class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/AberturaEJBRemoteRef" />
        <property name="businessInterface" value="br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote" />
    </bean>


<bean id="acompanhamentoWebService"  class="br.com.zzz.xxx.integracaosinistro.servacompws.webservice.AcompanhamentoWebService">
        <property name="abertura">
            <ref bean="abertura" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Inside a class, I'm doing this:

```
@Service
@WebService
public class AcompanhamentoWebService {
    
  @Autowired(required = true)
    private AberturaEJBRemote abertura;
...
```

The second one Spring can't understand that it is a bean.

On the first configuration attempt, with *jee:remote-slsb*, here I'm getting error after call the EJB method:

```
name: ejb/AberturaEJBRemoteRef#br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote: First component in name AberturaEJBRemoteRef#br.com.zzz.xxx.servcaptura.abertura.ejb.AberturaEJBRemote not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

I really don't know if I am trying this correctly, cause I never work with EJB before.
Call the remote inside the jar is a correct approach?

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Sorry for the bad English.
Thanks.

---

UPDATE

I founded an example and it seems that my approach is ok. But it missing an EJB configuration inside Websphere. To call the EJB remotely, I read that I will need the server informations where the EJB is stored and available.
And I don't have this information yet.

I think that I could access the methods from EJB directly from the jar. But I understood that it's not like this.

I will come back here when the problem was solved or another information appears.

Comment: Is your Spring app deployed in the same server that EJB that you want to connect to?

Comment: No. Im trying to create a remote connection with the ejb server. Im waiting the url address to keep with this.